# Merge two BibTeX files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I was constructing a BibTeX file for my Thesis. At the middle of that I had copied that bib file to another document I had to produce, I had to add some new citations to the copy of the original.

Now I have 2 bib files that have a lot in common but differ in some citations. Is there a way to merge them? So that I have one single file with all the citations from both files but no duplicates?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. (I don't know how to mark it) And I have solved the problem with BibDesk for Mac OS.

Comment: This question is not related to TeX. There are a lot of programs that can merge text files. In Linux you can try with [Kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) or [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/). In Windows  [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is fine. The merge process might be automatic (if you just appended the citations), but it will propably need some manual handling (especially if you changed the data on some refs).

Comment: @pmav99 I think the TeX in BibTeX is enough to warrant a place here. Also WinMerge, Kdiff and all `diff` like tools work on a line-by-line basis, whereas BibTeX files work on entries and not lines.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`bibtool -s bibliography1.bib bibliography2.bib` will merge two bib files, keeping duplicate entries. `bibtool -s -d bibliography1.bib bibliography2.bib` will merge two bib files, commenting out one of the duplicated entries (not sure which one). For more info, see [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/bibtool.pdf).

[Bibtool](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool)
is on CTAN. Not to be confused with [bibtools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtools) which is also on CTAN and probably also has the capacity to do this sort of thing...

Bibtool can also be found in Ubuntu repositories. (I wasn't able to compile the one from CTAN)

Comment: The current version of `bibtool` clings to duplicate entries. Removing them requires multiple steps: (a) pass `-d` on the command line, (b) create a resource file containing the entry `print.deleted.entries = off`, then (c) mention the resource file with `-r` on the command line. It does still work though, after all that.

Comment: To obtain a bibtex file, running `bibtool -s -d input1.bib input2.bib -o output.bib` on Ubuntu was satisfactory for me.

Comment: To avoid changing capitalization and also the duplicated entries on the merged file we can use  
`bibtool --preserve.key.case=on --print.deleted.entries=off -s -d input1.bib input2.bib -o output.bib`

Answer (score 55):

[JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/) is a bibliography manager that has tools for merging bib-files. Or rather, for importing one file into another: **File --> Import --> Import into current library**. It checks for duplicates on import as far as I can see, but there is a separate tool for checking for duplicates as well: **Quality --> Find duplicates**.

Comment: +2 for Jabref.  I normally don't fall for GUI programs.  But Jabref did the merging quite well.  Whats more, it arranged the new database alphabetically, something I had been wanting to do for a while.

Comment: One can select "Deselect all duplicates" right before merging the two databases and thus obtain a set of unique references.

Comment: Damn, it changed the BibTeX entry key for me!!

Comment: @cryptic0, is that an option, or is that forced upon you. I would see messing up your ordering as a massive downside (admitting that mixing two bibtex files inherently messes up ordering somewhat).

Comment: Jabref 5.7: Tools does not contain an option "Scan database".

Comment: @Kvothe No, it seems the program has changed since the answer was written. But a quick look through the menus revealed Quality -> Find duplicates. (Which you've probably found yourself by now ..)

Answer (score 12):

I think there is no easy way to do this. Though it is possible to write a perl script alike to use regex to do this. But the problem is

1. Sometimes two entries are duplicates though they are not exactly the same, for example different capitalization in titles or extra `{`and `}`. So we have to workaround this by define some threshold for difference.
2. Sometimes two entries from the same author of the same year with a little difference in the title are indeed two papers. This make the threshold in (1) hard to define.

So I suggest you can only do this by hand. A relative easier way is do it with a BibTeX editor, for example BibDesk on Mac OS X. Import both files into it, and it shall warn you when two entries have the same citekey. So for those entries with same citekeys, which are almost surely duplicates, you can clean them up easily. If I remember correctly BibDesk and other editors do have this functionality. After this, sort all entries by title, and spot further duplicates by your eyes.

Comment: I had BibDesk, but I did not know of this feature. Sure made my life easier.

Comment: I think it is a shame that this is the accepted answer given that there are two good ways to do this suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Just to re-ensure Torbjorn's point, JabRef checks for duplicates when using File -->Import into current database. [image: D indicating duplicate entries in current bib database]

Entries marked with "D" are duplicates found by JabRef 2.10. You can then use "Deselect All Duplicate" button to get rid of the duplicates.

Thanks

Comment: Tried to import my bibliography into Jabref and it became unresponsive for many hours, so I definitely do not recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

***Obviously you should not delete the original database files until you are certain you no longer need them. Add a couple of extra years after you are really sure, just to be on the safer side of certain.***

## *Caveat emptor ...*

Biber can do this. In `tool` mode, it removes entries with duplicate keys by default.

Note that this assumes that it is not necessary to merge *entries*, but only to ensure that exactly one copy of each entry with a unique bibkey ends up in the merged `.bib` file.

For example if you have something like

```
@article{bernard-travels,
  author = {Dickens, Bernard R.},
  year = 2003,
  pages = {3--4},
  volume = 4,
  journal = {Travelling}}

@book{bertha-stargazing,
  author = {Smithson, Bertha},
  year = 1987,
  publisher = {Great Discoveries},
  address = {Mars},
  title = {Stargazing for Gazelles}}
```

in one file and

```
@article{liz-tricks,
  author = {Davies, Elizabeth H.},
  year = 2010,
  pages = {31--43},
  volume = 56,
  journal = {Magicians' Monthly}}

@book{bertha-stargazing,
  author = {Smithson, Bertha},
  year = 1987,
  publisher = {Great Discoveries},
  address = {Mars},
  title = {Stargazing for Gazelles}}
```

then all will be well. But if the second file contains, for example,

```
@article{bernard-travels,
  author = {Dickens, Bernard R.},
  year = 2007,
  pages = {23--41},
  volume = 12,
  journal = {Travelling Again}}

@book{bertha-stargazing,
  author = {Smithson, Bertha},
  year = 1987,
  isbn = {1234567890123},
  address = {Mars},
  title = {Stargazing for Gazelles}}
```

then the result will probably not be what you want.

However, assuming unique bibkeys for unique entries and no need to merge individually partial entries, begin by combining the `.bib` files into one large `.bib`.

Suppose your large `.bib` is called `big.bib`. Then

```bash
biber --tool --output-format bibtex --output-file merge.bib big.bib
```

will produce a combined `.bib` file, `merge.bib`, with entries sorted and de-duplicated.

```
biber --help
```

provides further details of the options available.

Comment: Tried to use this approach, but biber removed fields and changed field names as well, so it made a complete mess, definitely not recommended as well.

Answer (score 4):

To remove the duplicates in BibTex,   use the bibtex-tidy, a web app to format your BibTex source. Click the link to open it.
https://varhowto.com/how-to-remove-duplicates-in-bibtex-bib-file-latex/

Please find the source of bibtex-tidy at https://github.com/FlamingTempura/bibtex-tidy . According to the current description there you can use it

- in your browser
- with a command line interface (CLI)
- as a pre-commit-hook
- as a Javasrcipt or Typescript API

Example from the trial link https://flamingtempura.github.io/bibtex-tidy/ :

Before:
[image: initial bibtex]

After:
[image: after]

Comment: By far the most convenient. Especially since it allows to just drag a bunch of files in. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Jabref is better at detecting the duplicates than BibDesk. But, since BibDesk has AppleScript support, some people have written tools for cleaning duplicates. I recently discovered this cool tool by Andreas Fischlin's tools: http://se-server.ethz.ch/staff/af/bibdesk/. The script that says Clean Duplicates can be modified. I modified the CiteKey to Title; and, able to find more than 400 duplicates that both BibDesk and Jabref missed. You can find the modified version here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/naegllc0yaril4q/Cleanup%20Duplicates.scpt?dl=0

But, be careful. It is dangerous. It can delete non-duplicate entries if they have the same Title by chance.