# Is there a tool to merge many .bib files to a main bib file avoiding duplicates?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

For each article, I get a .bib file, then I have to copy it to the main bib file I'm using with bibtex. Is there tool, even outside of latex programming, to merge all .bib files to a single one and avoid duplication of references in the main bib file?

It may require to use another programming language to do it. I'm asking if there something already done. Otherwise I will code it in Python.

My code is like that:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Dick2009}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's clear that you're after updating the bib key. How are the articles and their bibliographies linked in your final `.tex`? For this to be done solely in (La)TeX, you'll have to show the setup...

Comment: Instead of `\cite{Dick2009}`, you probably use `\input{article1}` or `\include{article1}`, right?

Comment: No. I have, for example, Dick2009.bib and many other .bib files. Whenever I want to add a new reference, I download its .bib file, and paste it in the main.bib. But I spend too much time copying and pasting them and I know it's possible to code it. Imagine that I have a folder with many .bib files and I want to merge them and paste on the main.bib, but don't delete toher references that already were on the main.bib and aren't in the folder with many .bib files.

Comment: So if you have `\bibitem{key}{..}` in `filea.bib` and `\bibitem{key}{..}` in `fileb.bib`, how would you manage this duplicate `key`? Discard it in `fileb.bib`? Rename it to `fileb:key` in `fileb.bib`?

Comment: Another way to formulate the question is: use \addbibresource{} to a folder, is it possible?

Comment: Sure, use `\addbibresource{/foldera/filea} \addbibresource{/folderb/fileb}`. But that doesn't answer the question about how to handle duplicates.

Comment: No, use \addbibresource to ALL .bib files in a folder

Comment: I agree that it doesn't solve duplicates problem. I think I will program it in python. Then it will merge all, avoid duplicates, put in alphabetical order and everything I want. Then I share it here.

Comment: You can follow these guidelines: [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7653/5764) and use `\addbibresource`. Additionally, one could update `\bibitem` to modify duplicates...

Comment: Note: `\addbibresource`, by design, must be used for each file that is being loaded. This is because `biblatex` can handle other types of bibliography files besides the traditional `.bib` file of BibTeX.  In order to deal with duplicate entries, look at [`bibtool`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtool?lang=en) or the `tool mode` of the [`Biber` engine](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber) (which was developed for use with `biblatex`).
‎

Comment: Related: [Merge two BibTeX files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20027/5764)

Comment: `JabRef` has functions `Append to database`, `Import into current database` and `Import into new database`.

Comment: tool mode of biber will do this. It will skip duplicates and you can sort the output however you want.

Comment: Would you consider your question to be a duplicate of [Merge two BibTeX files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20027/5764)? If not, can you explain what you need in more detail?

Comment: @moewe: Ah, one must appreciate the irony of a question about merging duplicate entries being marked as a duplicate :-)