# Seamless invocation of bib de-duplication script from document source preamble?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, shell-escape, scripts, multiple-citations

Unfortunately, for reasons beyond my control, I am stuck with `mendeley` as my citation manager which provides an option to export its library to a `bib` file.

My `mendeley` library is organised into folders of relevent topics. I have a few identical entries in two folders, because there is a large overlap in the technical areas/topics pertinent to those folders, e.g. `paper "x"` may be in `topic A (folder A)`, but also equally belongs to `topic B (folder B)`. This results in duplicate entries in the exported `bib` file.

There is a point-n-click style `deduplication` facility provided within `mendeley` akin to similar functionality in `jabref`,`endnote` and the other such tools.  However, I do not wish to use such a procedure for two reasons.

1. My citation manager (in conjunction with its cloud interface) is the only way I organise my reference literature for later reading. This helps to provide a portable way to manage a large library across multiple devices. I wish to retain `paper "x"` in both `folder A` and `folder B`, since at times I want to read on `topic A` and other times on `topic B`, e.g. I sometimes use the `sort-by-year` option within a certain topic, and I don't want to miss out on `paper x` just because it has been de-duplicated.
2. Point and click interfaces are not conducive to seamless workflow. Currently, I am writing a thesis. As I collect more references in my library on the fly(a few simultaneously go to `topic A` and `topic B`), they are continuously exported by `mendeley` to a `bib` file, resulting in a mess of duplicates. This necessitates a manual point and click de-duplication procedure which defeats #1 above and is also tedious.

I understand that de-deduplication of `bibtex` entries is hard. I am only talking about de-duplication of absolutely identical entries. But given its utility, is there any script (shell, perl, python or others) that can handle this de-duplication gracefully. Again, invoking this script from the command-line interface is tedious, and so an automated solution to call this script from the `main.tex` document (perhaps a line of code in the preamble resembling `\bibtexdedup{}`) would be advantageous. I am thinking to something like `makeindex` or `makeglossaries` which use the `shell-escape` mechanism to do their job.

Is there any solution available that will achieve these goals?

Comment: I suppose `bibtool` could help you if the keys of duplicate entries could be guaranteed to coincide (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76420/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20027/35864), but I assume this is not the case. Then it of course gets much harder to de-duplicate entries. I believe JabRef has a command line interface, but I don't know if it can be used to de-duplicate.

Comment: @moewe Yes. They are identical, since I deliberately save duplicates to different folders using ```mendeley web importer``` plugin. I looked at jabref CLI, but this page is sparse. How would one call it from the source document? Is my case valid enough to somehow entice the elder geeks here? Using another full-blown citation manager doesn't sound elegant. Shouldn't we look for a ```do one thing well``` solution. We have a ```bib``` file in plain text. We have one task - dedup it. I thought sed, awk, or their elder brother perl might be upto the task with some seriously-heavy regex-fu.

Comment: Ohh, in that case do have a look at `bibtool`.

Comment: @moewe thank you. I had looked at ```bibtool```. It does not mention the word ```duplicate``` anywhere in its manual. Can you maybe point out specifically to the section that could potentially help me. How could I call ```bibtool``` from within the preamble every time I compile my document? I am looking for something like ```\makeglossaries{}```

Comment: §A.13.1. Finding Double Entries, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20027/35864

Comment: @moewe thank you. I shall indeed take a look.

Comment: You can call arbitrary programmes from TeX if shell escape/write 18 is enabled: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20444/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5433/35864

Comment: Why do you care about duplicates? Imho biber will simply ignore a duplicate entry, and perhaps issue a warning but not more.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But is the OP using Biber? But I completely agree, in this situation, if using Biber, I think just ignoring duplicates makes most sense.

Comment: I can use biber, but most journals prefer bibtex+natbib. I also want to share the library with my supervisors and co-authors and would like to give them a small, clean file without 300 duplicate entries.

Comment: @cfr I thought I remember Krishna would use it, but bibtex skips repeated entries too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer BibTeX seems to belong to another world. I no longer remember what it does or doesn't do. :(

Comment: @cfr I didn't remember either. I had to run a small test ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
biber --tool duplicates.bib
```

This will create a `duplicates-bibertool.bib` without duplicates.

Comment: Great. Thank you. That will work. The solution for bibtex+natbib will be ```bibtool``` I guess. I shall call these accordingly with ```shell-escape```.

Comment: @Krishna You can use Biber for this. All it is doing is rewriting the `.bib`.

Comment: You can as cfr wrote, use `biber --tool` always. It is a generic tool to rewrite bib-files. Check the documentation.