# using more than one bibtex file in a single latex project

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, thesis

I'm curious how those research books composed of many research articles, each with hyperlinked references, are able to use multiple bibtex file in a single project. Is there a way so that I could build one bibfile for general references, and then in my manuscript, I wanna include all the research papers I've written or published regarding the same study so that they have their own bibfiles too? For Example, Chapters 1 to 4 are gonna use the general references bibfile and then Chapters 5 and 6, since they would be separate scientific papers, have their own bibfile as well.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84099/bibliographies-from-multiple-bib-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84099/bibliographies-from-multiple-bib-files)

Comment: Can you add a few more details about your general document and bibliography setup. It is easily possible to load several `.bib` files in one document, but if you have to 'keep them apart' for some reason, then things become more tricky.

Comment: Any news here? At the moment the question is very generic and the question linked in the first comment can be seen as a suitable duplicate for the question as it stands now, but I suppose you have a more specific and complex setup in mind. In that case it would be good if you could share a few relevant details so that an answer here can address those relevant points.

Comment: Well basically, i want a multiple chapter project that for example, each chapter is an individual scientific paper (so it would have its own references and thus its own bibfile). My problem is whether its possible. And a problem is: what if a certain reference appears in any of the bibfile? What happens to the number assigned to that reference?

Comment: @jboy I'm not sure that helps, the bib file doesn't really have anything to do with the citation or bibliography labels. Do you actually want to have multiple separate bibliographies? This could potentially be a dupe of any of 1. [Bibliographies from multiple .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84099/106162) 2. [Merge two BibTeX files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20027/106162) 3. [Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98660/106162)